# Graphics.CopyFromScreen from Web = The handle is invalid

Tags: asp.net, graphics

In an asp.net app, I try to get screenshot of server. Code works OK in VS.NET's web server but on IIS (even on local) I get the error.
I've tried checking WWW Service's "Service Interacts with Desktop" property but didnt work.
Any ideas?

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to do, but it sounds like you want to do something from a web application. In that case, copying something from the screen is meaningless, as the server does not have a screen (in the sense that any screen connected to the server does not exist for the web application).

Comment: I am trying to send "server"'s screenshot; another application will be kept running there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the IIS server runs as a service so there's no Desktop to get a handle to, im not sure how that would work.